# SAP NetWeaver Application Server ABAP 7.03 trial, error during installation

Tags: abap

Any suggestion as how to solve this installation error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check max db log file given in first image.

Answer (score 0):

Problem eventually solved by copying of [c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc] folder to [c:\windows\SysWOW64\drivers].